# Type conversion of string to int

Tags: go

Ok, so I've been having difficulties with the type conversion of a string to byte write.  This is the compiler error:

> cannot use row[5] (type uint8) as type string in function argument
>
> cannot use &v (type *Field) as type int in function argument

This is an example of row[5]: $15,000.00

Ive declared a struct:

```
type Field struct {
Eia uint8
}
```

here is the main implementation:

```
for {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var v Field
    for _, row := range record {
        eia, err := strconv.ParseInt(row[5], 8, &v) // Estimated Incoming Amount
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
        }
```

Can anyone please explain to me how strconv can convert the row to a integer?

Comment: You have to cast row[5] into a string first. Also, you remove that superfluous &v

Comment: I failed to mention row[5] is read from csv/encoding package.  Therefore, it is already a string by default.

Comment: You did not show the tyoe of record to us. It's difficult to help with insufficient information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made a complete example on http://play.golang.org/ it'd be easier to give you a complete solution.

ParseInt() takes the string (you might have to do `string(row[5])`), the base (you probably meant 10) and the bitsize (that's where you should put 8).

It retuns an int (eia), it doesn't put it into the struct as it looks like you are trying.

Instead do `if err == nil { v.Eia = eia }`.

Comment: Well I managed to get string conversion working properly by first casting a string variable and parsing it with the correct base and bitsize as you mentioned.  Here it is:  http://play.golang.org/p/qUIF3dRIat

Comment: The only caveat to the solution was that I had to eliminate the dollar sign ($) as it would result in an invalid syntax conversion error.

Comment: You can use `strings.TrimLeft` to remove any leading characters you you don't want, for example http://play.golang.org/p/GNhp8lLwdl